# how to pass a string to to an xpath?

Tags: python, string, xpath

I have an xpath in the following format

```
xpath='//*[@id="peoplegrid"]/div[5]/div[1]/a'
```

I want to pass a string to the first `div` in the x path in the following manner

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in x:
    xpath='//*[@id="peoplegrid"]/div[',+str(i),']/div[1]/a'
    print(xpath)
```

However when I run this, it states that `bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`

How can I pass a string to this xpath

Following is the full piece of code I am working on

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
for i in x:
    python_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="peoplegrid"]/div,'+[str(x)]+'/div[1]/a')
    python_button.click()
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Comment: Why did you place commas in this part of your XPATH: `div[',+str(i),']`?

Comment: @musikreck bascially I want to pass a set of integers in my list titled x to the first `div` in the XPATH

Comment: In your last snippet of code, why are you putting `str(x)` into brackets? For your purposes, it's unnecessary and going to throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot update @Steven's answer with such a subtle (less than 6 character) change, so I've created my own answer.

What you need is the following:

```
xpath='//*[@id="peoplegrid"]/div['+str(i)+']/div[1]/a'
```

As you can tell, between my answer and @Steven's answer, mine does not include the commas within the first `div` portion of the XPATH. For your purposes, it is unnecessary and invalid to place the commas in the string. Commas are typically used in `print` statements to prevent newlines from being appended to the output.

EDIT: In regards to the change to the original post and the comments therein, concatenating a list to a string is also invalid. Merely use an interpreter and try compiling the code, and a `TypeError: must be str, not list` will be thrown. This makes sense, since you cannot append a `list` directly to a `str`; however, if the contents of the `list` are strings, or can be converted to strings, then you can concatenate these. See [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) for an explanation of string concatentation in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the second `+`. Try something like this.

```
xpath='//*[@id="peoplegrid"]/div['+str(i)+']/div[1]/a'
```

Comment: Did you mean to backslash escape the quotes in the middle of the string as `\'`?

Comment: @NChauhan No, since he's doing string concatenation, escaping the quotes in the middle of the string is unnecessary and invalid.

Comment: Okay, my bad. But from my guess I don't think there should be those commas either side of `str(i)` in the left/right strings

Comment: I added them because they were in the original code, but you're right, they shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to avoid constructing the XPath expression by string concatenation. Disadvantages:

(a) you need to worry about escaping strings that contain special characters

(b) you need to REALLY worry about it if there's any possibility of people inserting bad strings maliciously (XPath injection attacks)

(c) you have to compile the expression each time it's used.

I don't know the Python API you are using, but most XPath APIs allow you to compile an expression containing variables (eg. `'//[@id="peoplegrid"]/div[$param]/div[1]/a'`) and then bind a value to the variable separately. If you can do this then it's much preferable and avoids the above disadvantages.